# Linq query returns unwanted results as well

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm new to `linq` and C#, trying to query complex objects by a certain property. The scenario is I have a list of `currentPerson` objects, which include `PersonAddressesDisplay` property, which is a string. I'm looping over the list of trying to find saved `person` objects in the DB by their address (`PersonAddressesDisplay`). Right now for some odd reason I get unwanted results as well (different strings also get in the `matchAddresses` list). The query is as follows:

```
        foreach(var currentPerson in PersonsListToSave) {
         .
         .
         .
         var matchAddresses = db.PersonAddresses.Include(p => p.Persons).AsEnumerable().
         Where(add => currentPerson.Addresses
          .Any(personAddress => personAddress.PersonAddressesDisplay == add.PersonAddressesDisplay)).ToList();
         // matchAddresses includes unwanted results
         .
         .
         .
        }
```

Comment: Please give an example of input & output.

Comment: While not answering your question, I wonder why the call to `AsEnumerable()`? That would pull the entire `PersonAddresses` table joined with `Persons` to memory before applying the `Where` filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract `PersonAddress`+`Person` objects which share at least address with the `currentPerson`, then you can construct a query for that purpose directly:

```
foreach(var currentPerson in PersonsListToSave)
{
    // ...
    IEnumerable<string> currentAddresses = 
        currentPerson.Addresses.Select(personAddr => personAddr.PersonAddressesDisplay);

    var matchAddresses = db.PersonAddresses.Include(p => p.Persons)
        .Where(addr => currentAddresses.Contains(addr.PersonAddressesDisplay))
        .ToList();
    // ...
}
```

I cannot try this code, but I think that it should work correctly by constructing the `WHERE - IN` SQL filter under the hood. Please try it out and send more info if this is not solving the issue.